# phpunit assert error, but when I check the page by myself. It looks fine

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am using laravel 5.4. is there some condition that phpunit test use the different page than myself?
btw, phpunit and I use the same user to login and test the same page.

```
$user = User::find(2);
$this->be($user);
$this->get('/groupproduct')->assertSee('Name');
```

It's a simple test. just wanna check "Name" to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$this->get('/groupproduct')->assertSeeText('Name');
```

Comment: It's not working. visit() see()  undefined method error.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please try now. If it doesn't work can you post your whole source code of the test file, also post output of  $this->get('/groupproduct')->dump();

Comment: Thank you Anshu! I found the reason, although you use same user login, and check the same page. There is still some difference. like session. the error is fixed. $this->get('/groupproduct')->assertSee('Name'); is fine.